# PhoneGap + Android page doesn't refresh after soft keyboard closes

Tags: android, cordova

Most of the time (but not always), when I finish typing in a  or  and the soft keyboard hides, the view area is left raised with a black space on the bottom.  Clicking, tilting or otherwise engaging the phone corrects the screen.  However, user's first motion is usually pressing , but if you click submit it jumps down and you actually just click on the text area again.  How do you stop this and get the screen to reset after the keyboard closes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at you AndroidManifest.xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

I think you need to change `android:configChanges`.

Comment: I've tried just about every possible combination of this ever since your answer.  It just doesn't help...  I'm starting to wonder if it could be css related in that it needs some sort of body{min-height: 100%} or something.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem what i did was handle hidekeyboard even in javascript and do something like window.scrollTo(0,0)  or $("input[type=text],textarea").blur();
This will cause the the screen to get back to normal position

But there is just one problem when click from input field of type = text to a input field password it internally hide the keyboard which causes the hidekeyboard event to fire and scrolls the screen to top. This is the only side effect of this

Let me know if you find the solution for this